# Objective C override %@ for custom objects

Tags: objective-c, nslog

I'd like to override the default print function in NSLog for custom objects;

For example:

```
MyObject *myObject = [[MyObject alloc] init];
NSLog(@"This is my object: %@", myObjcet);
```

Will print out:

```
This is my object: <MyObject: 0x4324234>
```

Is there a function I override in MyObject to print out a prettier description?

Cheers!
Nick.

Comment: Saw this note in my XCode 5.1 download details "Adds Quick Look support in the debugger for custom object types". Fingers crossed that it's all I am hoping from. Downloading now.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Just implement the `description` method.

```
- (NSString *)description {
     return @"MyCustomDescription";
}
```

This is the method used to print an instance.

Answer (score 8):

Override `-description` in your custom class.